# Regex match if statements that contain assignment operator

Tags: php, regex, match, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

My requirement is to match all if statements that erroneously contain assignment operator instead of an equality operator (==).

I am sure my regex lacks a lot but the first problem that I notice is that I am having trouble containing the regex to stop searching after an if statement closes e.g. ') {'.

```
if(.*?)(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)\)
```

Note: lines containing >= or != must not be matched

Comment: You’re not matching any opening parenthesis… but even then, with a regex, you can’t really make sure when the condition stops, since matching parentheses are not regular language.

Comment: I think I am by (.*?) . Am I wrong?

Comment: `(.*?)` matches just _any_ character, any number of times, as few times as possible, and captures it. There’s no `\(` or `[(]` or similar to match a literal `(`.

Comment: Try this: `if\s*\(\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)\s*\)`
.You can check the demo here: https://regex101.com/r/cl9HiI/2

Comment: You could also have no spaces, maybe `'/if.*?[^=!]=[^=].*?({|;)/s'`

Comment: For a single comparison with`==` in the if statement perhaps [`\bif\s*\([^=]+=[^=]+\)`](https://regex101.com/r/p1n3v9/1/)

Comment: @Saud check the updated test code. it does not match if the line is:
if (x == 2 and x=2 ){}

Comment: @AbraCadaver check https://regex101.com/r/cl9HiI/4 for the demo it does not match

Comment: After a lot of trying I came up with this:
if\s*\([^'"\n]*[^=!<>\n]+=[^=\n]+[^'"\n]*\)\s*\{

Comment: I've modifed my regex and posted it as an answer. It works fine now  (demo: https://regex101.com/r/cl9HiI/4) .

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`if\s*\([^{]*\s*\w+\s*=\s*\w+\s*[^{]*\)`

**How it's made:**
[image: Working]
You want to identify something like `num=3` inside the parenthesis of an if-statement. You can do this by using `if\(\w+=\w+\)`. However, there's a small problem with this. It fails in case of white space. So, it won't recognize `num = 3` or `apples   =   8`.

In order to make sure that our regex doesn't fail in case of white space, we modify it to: `if\s*\(\s*\w+\s*=\s*\w+\s*\)`. Now, it can work even with white spaces. That's good; but there's still a small problem that needs to be addressed (like you mentioned in the comments). What if we have an if-statement like `if ( apples==3 and mangoes=5 or oranges==4 )`? *Well, our regex will fail*.

To address this issue, modify your regex to `if\s*\([^{]*\s*\w+\s*=\s*\w+\s*[^{]*\)`. I have only added `[^{]*` to our regex. It tells the regex engine that there could be any number of characters (except `{`) before and after `\s*\w+\s*=\s*\w+\s*`.

That's it. You have a simple regex that matches all the if-statements which erroneously contain assignment operator instead of an equality operator.

Answer (score 1):

Just my five cents:

```
if(\s)*(\(){1}(.)+[^!=<>](=){1,1}?[^=]
```

This expression don't match "!=" "<=" ">=" that are valid logical operations.